# error '3706' en el tiempo de ejecucion: no se econtro el proveedor especificado

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

tengo una base de datos realizada en sql server que sirve como mi backend y tengo en access mi diseño que sirve como mi front end el problema que tengo es que en mi access quiero almacenar los datos ya sean nuevos o modificados a mi base de datos de `sql` pero cuando ejecuto mi comando me da el siguiente error:

> error '3706' en el tiempo de ejecución: no se encontro el proveedor
> especificado.

Es posible que no este instalado correctamente la conexión
la estoy realizando por medio de ADODB ya he verificado los parametros de conexión y esta bien desde mi equipo local me puedo conectar a la base de datos por medio del management el firewall no tiene bloqueo el puerto esta habilitado en el server pero aun así sigo con el mismo fallo no se que hacer para solucionar este problema.

Comment: Escribe la cadena de conexión que estás utilizando así cómo el código completo que te está dando ese error. Sin ver el código es imposible ni empezar a investigar.